# What's the lowest footprint way to isolate JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, html

I'm developing a HTML5 platform that involves potentially untrusted third-party developers to be able to write plugins for it (in JavaScript). What's the best way to isolate those plugins?

I'm currently using sandboxed offscreen iframes, but the memory footprint is pretty huge. Are there other lower-footprint ways to isolate JavaScript code?

In particular I'm looking for protection from:

- Two untrusted plugins should not be able to read each others' data.
- Plugins should not be able to read arbitrary sensitive data or cookies from the main platform and only be able to interact with the main platform via a provided API.
- Plugins should not be able to lock up the UI of the main platform.

iframes are great, but is it really necessary to launch a full-blown WebKit browser-in-a-browser to accomplish the above?

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://www.adsafe.org/

Comment: I think your assumption of how iframes are implemented inside WebKit might be off.  Chrome is working to implement something like this ((source)[http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/oop-iframes]) as part of a larger project called the [Site Isolation](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/site-isolation), but this is a 2015 initiative